# Return object after writing on topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I would like an object to be provided to the producer in case of writing to kafka. It's possible?

After writing on topic ther's a consumer that elaborate queue. A consumer generate unique id that must be returned to producer.

Additional info:

I would like to understand if it is possible, once the writing is finished (`producer.send()`) if it is possible to instruct kafka in order to populate `RecordMetadata` with additional information such as an object for example.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve but there is no direct communication channel between consumer and producer in Kafka, each of them plays only one role.
Maybe it is worth adding some details to your question. Here are some questions:
How can a producer use an id value provided by a consumer?
What is the structure of an object you are interested in? Is it some info about the writing process? If yes, then you can check a KafkaProcucer#send method with Callback (https://rb.gy/61bal)

Comment: I add additional info. Hope can help.

Comment: Please refer to OneCricketeer's answer, it should cover your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `.get()` on the Future object that `producer.send()` returns, then return the metadata, yes, but you cannot "add" random fields on-top of that. You would need to wrap the result in your own object type.

You may also want to look at `ReplyingKafkaTemplate` class from Spring-Kafka